# What is the use of "bash -c" command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

What is the use of `bash -c` command, while surfing on the internet I came across the command

```
ssh -t "${SSH_USER}@${SERVER_IP}" bash -c
```

First part here is doing ssh obviously to a server but what exactly `bash -c` is responsible for?

Comment: Do you know what `bash -c` does normally? If not, have you looked it up? If so, can you make it clear what you're actually asking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash -c` option with `ssh` is one such method to execute multi line commands on the ssh server with variable expansion.

Say you have

```
VAR1="Variable 1"
ssh app@HOSTNAME '
ls
pwd
if true; then
    echo "True"
    echo $VAR1      # <-- it won't work
else
    echo "False"
fi
'
```

But with bash -c

```
VAR1="Variable 1"
 ssh -t "${SSH_USER}@${SERVER_IP}" bash -c "'
ls
pwd
if true; then
    echo $VAR1     <-- This works
else
    echo "False"
fi
'"
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham for helping out :)

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from just removing the `bash -c` and the unnecessary outer double quotes from the command, though, so I don't think that this really answers the question.

Comment: @TomFenech if you remove bash -c the other way would be to have multiple commands separated with `;`

Comment: Newlines or semicolons make no difference in either case.

Comment: @TomFenech Multiline commands and variable expansion is what bash -c is used for.

Comment: Could you explain how using `bash -c` affects either of those two things?

Comment: Your example just shows the difference between single and double quotes.